# capture images from webcam display them on the same window and store in directory speciified by user using python tkinter and opencv

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter

I am trying to create a gui using tkinter in which a folder gets created in the C: drive under subdirectory "raw" with a user-specified entry in the entry widget.on creation of folder i want to click images from live webcam sequence for which i use opencv.  Problem: only a single image is getting captured!  I want to capture 30 images of the same person and store in C:/raw/s, where s is an user-specified directory.here is the code.I'm not sure why the img_counter variable is not getting updated.Any inputs would be highly appreciated

```
import tkinter as tk

import cv2
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import os
import tkMessageBox
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

width, height = 800, 600
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
flag,frame=cap.read()

#cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, width)
#cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, height)
global img_counter

root = tk.Tk()
root.bind('<Escape>', lambda e: root.quit())
lmain = tk.Label(root)
lmain.pack()
tk.Label(text='Enter your name')

entry = tk.Entry(root, width=10)
entry.pack(side=tk.TOP,padx=10,pady=10)

#e = Entry(root,width=10)
#e.pack(side=TOP,padx=10,pady=10)

entry.delete(0, tk.END)
entry.insert(0, "username")

def onok():
    s = entry.get()
    mypath='C:\\raw\\'
    mypath=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(mypath), s)
    os.mkdir(mypath, 0777)
    tkMessageBox.showinfo(title=s,message="Your name is now entered.Start  taking images")
    entry.destroy()
#tk.Button(root,text='click',command=onclick).pack()
    img_counter = 0
    click_button = tk.Button(master=root, text='Click', command=lambda: saveImage(img_counter))
    click_button.pack()

def saveImage(img_counter):


    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow("test", frame)


    img_name = "opencv_frame_{}.png".format(img_counter)



    cv2.imwrite(img_name, frame)
    print("{} written!".format(img_name))
    img_counter += 1

tk.Button(root, text='OK', command=onok).pack(side=tk.LEFT)
#tk.Button(root, text='CLOSE').pack(side= tk.RIGHT)

def show_frame():
    _, frame = cap.read()
    frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
    cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
    img = Image.fromarray(cv2image)
    imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
    lmain.imgtk = imgtk
    lmain.configure(image=imgtk)
    lmain.after(10, show_frame)

show_frame()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: thank you!!.i am a newbie to python and opencv.i fixed the rest of my code.Now it does what i intended in the first place. Thanks again@CommonSense

Comment: glad to help! And look on your imports! You importing `tkinter` twice! You can get rid of `from tkinter import *` line. When you import with asterisk you import all stuff in current namespace, so you can declare/use constants without `tk.` prefix. Since you use `tk.` prefix there is no reason for second import at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm not sure why the img_counter variable is not getting updated

First of all you need to read about mutable and immutable objects in Python and so far integers are [immutable ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37535694/why-are-integers-immutable-in-python).

After that you declare the global `img_counter` and trying to [pass it by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference) to the function.
So you got access to value but can't modifie it because you use `global` keyword incorrectly. With `global` keyword you can [bind variable within a scope](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html) of desired function! Take a look at code below:

```
# declare global
counter = int()

# let's try to counter
def try_to_counter():
    global counter
    counter += 1

# simple loop
def main_loop():
    for _ in range(5):
        try_to_counter()
        print(counter)

main_loop()
```

With `global` keyword you can declare global variables inside a function (don't do that!)

```
# let's try to counter
def try_to_counter():
    global counter
    if 'counter' not in globals():
        counter = int()
    counter += 1

# simple loop
def main_loop():
    for _ in range(5):
        try_to_counter()
        print(counter)

main_loop()
```

As you see in both cases there's no need to pass something to function! So in you code you can get rid of lambda function.

```
...
img_counter = int()
...
click_button = tk.Button(master=root, text='Click', command=saveImage)
...
def saveImage():
    global img_counter
    ...
    img_counter += 1
...
```

Afterwords:
[Best way to structure a tkinter application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466561/best-way-to-structure-a-tkinter-application)