# Please, could someone find the error in my code?

Tags: python

```
def factorial(n):
    sum = 0;
    if (n==0 or n==1):
        return 1
    else:
        While(n!=0)
            sum = sum + factorial(n);
            n = n - 1;
            return sum

factorial(3);
```

python 3.6
i need to find this: 1! + 2! + ... + n!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you elaborate on how your code ["doesn't work"](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/)? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide a description of the error, what version of Python you are using and what you are trying to achieve in general. This helps us help you :)

Comment: While(n!=0) -> while(n!=0):

Comment: no need for `;`

Comment: Please note that factorial uses multiplication, not addition (see https://www.wikipedia.com/en/Factorial)

Comment: Or `()` around flow-control expressions. Note: this recursion never terminates because you are not change `n` before recursing.

Comment: Integers are immutable. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37535694/why-are-integers-immutable-in-python and use a debugger (https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) it will help learn faster

Answer (score 1):

```
def factorial(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * factorial(n-1)
factorial(3)
```

This will return 6

You are attempting to use a recursive function, which is fine, but the argument needs to be changed, in this case `factorial(n-1)`

Answer (score 1):

try

```
In [3]: def factorial(n):
   ...:     if n == 0:
   ...:         return 1
   ...:     return n * factorial(n-1)
   ...: factorial(3)
   ...:
Out[3]: 6
```

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to build up than descend given you want to efficiently calculate this factorial sum. E.g. `f` is the increasing factorial, `t` is the total of those factorials:

```
def fac_sum(n):
    t, f = 0, 1
    for x in range(1, n+1):
        f *= x
        t += f
    return t

In []:
fac_sum(3)

Out[]:
9
```

Note: you can use [`itertools.accumulate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) to simplify:

```
import itertools as it
import operator as op

def fac_sum(n):
    return sum(it.accumulate(range(1, n+1), op.mul))
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using recursive in a bad way.
Recursive and while are not good friends.

If you omit the while and do

```
        sum = sum + factorial(n-1);
```

That should works