# Why a dictionary will be changed by a class instance, but an integer won't

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm learning about python class. In a toy python script,

```
class test():
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.new = a
        self.old = b

    def another_one(self):
        temp = self.new
        for key in temp.keys():
            temp[key] += 1

    def old_one(self):
        old = self.old
        old += 1

a = {'1': 1, '2': 2, '3': 3, '4': 4, '5': 5}
b = 5
test_pass = test(a, b)
test_pass.another_one(), test_pass.old_one()
a, b
```

I found that by running the method `another_one` of instance `test_pass`, dictionary `a` will be changed. However, integer `b` will not be altered by running the method `old_one`.

Why a dictionary will be changed while an integer will not?

Comment: Mostly because dicts are mutable and integers aren't

Comment: Watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_AEJHKGk9ns) then report back if there's still confusion.

Comment: https://medium.com/@meghamohan/mutable-and-immutable-side-of-python-c2145cf72747

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37535694/why-are-integers-immutable-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python integers are immutable, you can't change them *in-place*.

Take a look at the following snippet:

```
x = 2
print(id(x))
x += 1
print(id(x))

x = [2]
print(id(x))
x += [1]
print(id(x))
```

You can see that the first part, where the integer is being modified, the unique `id()` of the object changes. Afterwards `x` is a completely different object.

When modifying the list, its 'id()' does not change, the list is changes *in-place*.

The integer is immutable, they can't be magically turn into something different. Lists can.