# Is it possible to pass a numpy array by reference into a cpdef function?

Tags: python, numpy, cython

Is it possible to write a **Cython** function where a **numpy array** is passed **by reference** (perhaps a memory view?) and can I use such function in **Python**?

I tried:

```
cpdef void my_function(bytes line, int& counter, np.ndarray[np.uint32_t, ndim=2]& sums):
    ...
    ...
```

Here `counter` and `sums` would be passed by reference. I am interested in the latter (but will happily accept critics and suggestions regarding both).

The compiler throws:

```
Reference base type cannot be a Python object
```

I get the same message with `cdef` either and I don't understand the full etiology of the problem.

Comment: Tell us about the array?  `shape`, and especially `dtype`.

Comment: @hpaulj `unsigned integers` and `shape = (76 x 74)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - sort of.

A Numpy array is a Python object. All Python objects are passed "by reference" anyway (i.e. if you change the contents of a Numpy array inside the function you change it outside).

Therefore you just do

```
cpdef void my_function(bytes line, int& counter, np.ndarray[np.uint32_t, ndim=2] sums):
```

Specifying it as a C++ reference doesn't really make much sense. For a Python object there's quite a bit of detail that Cython hides from you.

---

However, `cpdef` functions are designed to be callable from Python and Cython. Python ints (and other numeric types) [are immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37535694/why-are-integers-immutable-in-python). Therefore changing `counter` *will not work as you think* when called from Python, and if it did what you hoped it'd potentially break the interpreter.

I'd therefore avoid using references in `cpdef` functions (and probably mostly avoid `cpdef` functions completely - it's usually better just to decide on `def` or `cdef`)