# Is there a way to replace variables in for loops?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop

I am trying to create a for loop like this:

```
list = [a, b, c, a_1, b_1, c_1]
for i  in list:
    if str(i).endswith(".0"):
        i = int(i)
print(type(a))
```

This outputs:

```
<class 'float'>
```

This means that the for loop didn't define the entry into an integer.
I checked if this works to make sure it was the for loop:

```
if str(i).endswith(".0"):
    i = int(i)
```

Does anyone know why the for loop wouldn't define the variable the same as outside of the loop?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are integers immutable in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37535694/why-are-integers-immutable-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

The reason `a` is not being edited is that `i` is first assigned to the same value as `a`, then `i` is assigned to a different value without modifying `a`. Python has no way to get references to variables so that they can be edited. One workaround is to use indirection: create an object with an attribute to store the value, then `i` will point to the same object as `a`, and modifying the attribute of the object modifies both `a.value` and `i.value`:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Any

@dataclass
class Box:
    value : Any

# note that the values are constructed like `Box(0.2)`
a, b, c, a_1, b_1, c_1 = (Box(i/10) for i in range(6))


list = [a, b, c, a_1, b_1, c_1]
for i  in list:
    if str(i.value).endswith(".0"):
        i.value = int(i.value)
print(type(a.value))
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assign a value to floats object. What you are trying to do is:

```py
# something like
# assume  i = 5.0
# if str(i).endswith('.0'):
#    i = int(i)
# if str(5.0).endswith('.0'):
#      5.0 = 5 

# what you want

list_ = [a, b, c, a_1, b_1, c_1]
for index, value  in enumerate(list_):
    if str(value).endswith(".0"):
        list_[index] = int(value)

a, *rest = list_
print(type(a))
```

Note: `list` is python keyword. Avoid overriding it.

#### demo

```py
list_ = [1.0, 2, 1, 5.0]
for index, value  in enumerate(list_):
    if str(value).endswith(".0"):
        list_[index] = int(value)

a, *rest = list_
print(type(a))
# class 'int'>
```

Comment: Thanks! I do have one question though. What is the `a, *rest = list_` part of the code?

Comment: Ah, I want to take the first value of the list_, and assign it to a, and pass the rest to rest variable. The result `a=1, rest = [2, 1, 5]`