# Why does changing one Python list element change all the others?

Tags: python, dictionary, deep-copy

I have some code where I make a dictionary and each value is the list `[0,0]`. I found that incrementing any list index would increment each value's corresponding index; i.e. `d[key][0] += 1` would increment each other list's 0 index.

I assumed Python's shallow copying of the list was to blame, since my dictionary was constructed using `dict.fromkeys(keys, [0,0])`. However, I had the same problem when using `copy.deepcopy` on the list.
I then tried dictionary comprehension: `{key:[0,0] for key in keys}`. This works as I would expect; modifying one list does not affect the others.

Since I've found a solution to this issue, my actual question is **why** this is the case. It seems that either I'm mistaken about how `deepcopy` works or that it's irrelevant to the issue at hand, but I don't know what else would cause this.

This is a full snippet that reproduces the behavior:

```py
import copy
keys = [i for i in range(5)]
l = [0,0]
d = dict.fromkeys(keys, copy.deepcopy(l))
#d = {key:[0,0] for key in keys} # this approach works as expected
d[0][0] += 1
print(d)
# expected: {0: [1, 0], 1: [0, 0], 2: [0, 0], 3: [0, 0], 4: [0, 0]}
# actual: {0: [1, 0], 1: [1, 0], 2: [1, 0], 3: [1, 0], 4: [1, 0]}
```

Comment: Hint: when you write `f(a, b)`, how many times does `b` get evaluated?

Comment: When you use `dict.fromkeys(keys, [0,0])`, or even `copy.deepcopy(l)` you are assigning the same list object as the value for each key in the dictionary. This means that modifying one list will affect all the other lists because they are essentially references to the same object.

Comment: Side note: `dict.fromkeys(keys, [0,0])` doesn't actually make shallow copies of `[0, 0]` (if it did, your problem would be solved). Rather, it's using references to the _exact same_ list multiple times. Also you may be interested to know that for lists of integers, there's actually zero difference between shallow and deep copies (see [immutability of integers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37535694/11082165))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, `deepcopy` is not helping the issue, it's `dict.fromkeys` functionality.
From the documentation at https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys

> All of the values refer to just a single instance, so it generally doesn’t make sense for value to be a mutable object such as an empty list. To get distinct values, use a dict comprehension instead.

You are passing in a single list to `fromkeys` for the value argument. So every key in the dict refers to one list, which just happened to be deepcopied from `l`.

So it seems like your dict comprehension is the recommended method. Since you are making a new list for each element, with `[0, 0]`, they stay independent.

Answer (score 1):

You're only making one copy of the list, and using this for every value in the dictionary. Function arguments are only evaluated once, and the result is passed to the function. So when you write

```
d = dict.fromkeys(keys, copy.deepcopy(l))
```

it's effectively equivalent to

```
temp = copy.deepcopy(l)
d = dict.fromkeys(keys, temp)
```

Use a dictionary comprehension instead, so you make a new copy for each element.

```
d = {key: copy.deepcopy(l) for key in keys}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make the dictionary in a different way. There isn't really the need for `copy.deepcopy` here.

```
keys = list(range(5))
values = [[0,0] for _ in keys]
d = dict(zip(keys, values))

#one-liner: d = {k:[0,0] for k in range(5)}

d[0][0] += 1
print(d) #{0: [1, 0], 1: [0, 0], 2: [0, 0], 3: [0, 0], 4: [0, 0]}
```